# Routify exact path for using isActive?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, routify

I'm building a restaurant review site using Svelte and Routify, I have a path "./reviews" that shows the current user's own reviews, and paths for reviews on different categories of restaurants, i.e. "./reviews/mexican" or "./reviews/asian", when the I click on the Mexican's tab, both the "./reviews" and "./reviews/mexican" seem to get turned on as isActive, how do I set exact paths in Routify?

Thanks!

Comment: you could subscribe to the `$params` store (it'll emit a new value on each url change) then within the callback of the subscription assign `window.location.pathname` to a local variable, then couple up that variable + `$isActive` to exclude `./reviews/`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
$isActive('/path/to/component', { /* params */ }, { strict: true})
```

With strict set to false, the path would default to `/path/to/component/index` and thus wouldn't match any descendent components.

https://routify.dev/docs/helpers#is-active